# Angular 2+ (angular2-datatable) - Sorting rows by values of row property that is array with mfDefaultSorter

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable

Is there a way to sort orders by the sum of the items quantity (without changing the structure of the orders array):

```
const orders = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Order 1'
    items: [
      {quantity: 20},
      {quantity: 30},
      {quantity: 40},
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Order 2'
    items: [
      {quantity: 50},
      {quantity: 10},
    ]
  }
];
```

template:

```
<mfDefaultSorter [by]="?????">Quantity</mfDefaultSorter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mfDefaultSerter uses lodash [sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#sortBy)

you can try:

```
...
sortByQuantity(order) {
   return order.items.reduce((sum, _order) => sum + _order.quantity, 0);
}
...
<mfDefaultSorter [by]="sortByQuantity">Quantity</mfDefaultSorter>
...
```